# Reading and processing a large CSV in OCaml without loading it all into memory

Tags: csv, ocaml, data-science

Coming from Python data science, I want to read and process a large CSV of data with OCaml without bringing it all into memory.

I previously got it done, albeit as a beginner, in F# with the [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) package which I could use to read a very large Csv file into a `Seq` and process with things like `Seq.countBy`, `Seq.groupBy` etc.

How do would people suggest I do similar things in OCaml?

Comment: what about ocaml-csv : https://math.umons.ac.be/anum/software/csv/Csv/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, indeed I've seen _only_ that package. I had a little go with it and will try some more, but I was struggling to find any examples of how to get that into a `Seq`. Plus I did not see any `Seq.countBy` or `Seq.groupBy` in OCaml ... maybe I would just need to write them myself?

Comment: @Robert there are many functions implemented in the oseq package: https://github.com/c-cube/oseq . You should be able to use e.g. https://c-cube.github.io/oseq/0.3/oseq/OSeq/index.html#val-fold to implement `countBy`/`groupBy`.

Comment: @PierreG. does the ocaml-csv file allow 'streaming' -- it does not load the whole CSV into memory, but only piece-by-piece as you e.g. run a map on the sequence?